# BackGroundWorker not working in VSTO Outlook

Tags: sharepoint, vsto

I am working on a VSTO Outlook addin which is uploading emails to sharepoint document library but the critical problem is that even using BackGroundWorker I am unable to use Outlook while uploading process is going on.

The code is as follows.

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext()); 
bw = new BackgroundWorker(); 
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true; 
bw.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
   { 
      bw_DoWork(sender, e, uploadData); 
   }; 
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
```

If anybody knows how to solve it please help me quick in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a breakpoint on your upload implementation, and open the threads window in Visual Studio to verify which thread it is running on.

If it is running on the correct thread, you should then check if your progress reporting logic is locking the UI thread (e.g. the event might be firing too often).

Finally, you could be experiencing problems because the implementation of the upload method is accessing Outlook COM objects directly in some way.